# Dodged geom_errorbar with geom_bar using fill, colour, and alpha

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, facet-wrap, geom-bar

I am attempting to make a facet_wrap bar_graph with error bars (se) that clearly shows three different categorical variables (Treatment, Horizon, Enzyme) with one response variable (AbundChangetoAvgCtl).  Below is the code for some dummy data followed by the ggplot code I have so far.  The graphs I've made can be see at this link:
[bargraph figures](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g1e3f2aig1l4mdn/AAAlC1VpvGqCmcv1qXY8GmaKa?dl=0)

```
Enzyme <- c("Arabinosides","Arabinosides","Arabinosides","Arabinosides","Arabinosides","Arabinosides","Cellulose","Cellulose","Cellulose","Cellulose","Cellulose","Cellulose","Chitin","Chitin","Chitin","Chitin","Chitin","Chitin","Lignin","Lignin","Lignin","Lignin","Lignin","Lignin")
Treatment <- c("Deep","Deep","Int","Int","Low","Low","Deep","Deep","Int","Int","Low","Low","Deep","Deep","Int","Int","Low","Low","Deep","Deep","Int","Int","Low","Low")
Horizon <- c("Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min","Org","Min")
AbundChangetoAvgCtl <- rnorm(24,mean=0,sd=1)
se <- rnorm(24, mean=0.5, sd=0.25)
notrans_noctl_enz_toCtl_summary <- data.frame(Enzyme,Treatment,Horizon,AbundChangetoAvgCtl,se)
ggplot(notrans_noctl_enz_toCtl_summary, aes(x=Horizon, y=AbundChangetoAvgCtl, fill=Horizon, alpha=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), colour="black", stat="identity", aes(fill=Horizon)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=AbundChangetoAvgCtl-se, ymax=AbundChangetoAvgCtl+se),
            width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  labs(y = "Rel Gene Abundance Change / Control", x="") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=20),
        plot.title = element_text(size=22, vjust=2, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18),
        legend.key.size = unit(.75, "in"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
  facet_wrap(~Enzyme, scales="free")
```

(figure 1)

So this is close to what I want, however for some reason, the "alpha=Treatment" call in ggplot causes my errorbars to fade (which I don't want) as well as the bar_fill (which I do want).  I've tried moving the "alpha=Treatment" to the geom_bar call, as well as adding "alpha=1"  to geom_bar, but when I do that, the error bars all move to a single location and overlap (figure 2).

I initially wanted to cluster the bars within facet_wrap, but found the alpha option on this site, which seems to accomplish what I'm looking for as well.  Any help would be appreciated.  If there is a better way to represent all of this, those ideas are welcome as well.
Also, if there is a way to condense and clarify my legend, that would be extra bonus!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `Treatment` to the `group` option in the `ggplot()` command and then move the `alpha=Treatment` option to the `geom_bar()` command. Then the `alpha` value of `geom_errorbar` won't be affected by the global option and will be black. Like this:

```
ggplot(notrans_noctl_enz_toCtl_summary, aes(x=Horizon, y=AbundChangetoAvgCtl, fill=Horizon, group = Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), colour="black", stat="identity", aes(fill=Horizon, alpha = Treatment))
```

Also, I would check whether setting `alpha=Treatment` corresponds to more transparent as being equivalent to low treatment and less transparent to high treatment. At least that would be my intuitive understanding, without any background on the research design or data.

For information about formatting legends, see [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/).

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and it didn't seem to work.  I've added some example code above to give you something to work with.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Thanks for providing a reproducible example. I've edited my answer to include a working solution. Let me know if you encounter any problems with it.

Comment: Thank you SO much!! I was beating my head against the wall for hours on this one.  Figures that it was something so simple!  many thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe you can accept the answer as correct, so future readers will know that this is a valid solution to the question.